# Are filtered indexes in all editions of SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I cannot find anywhere conformation that filtered indexes are in editions of SQL Server 2008 other then developer and enterprise.

(Is the answer the same for SQL Server 2008 r2)

Comment: Where did you see only "developer and enterprise"?

Comment: @gbn, Advanced indexing tends to be grouped with "indexed views" in articles etc, and indexed views are enterprice only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inclined to believe they're supported in all editions. The Books Online article for CREATE INDEX specifically mentions that online and parallel indexing operations are supported only in Enterprise and Developer, but makes no mention of edition restrictions for filtered indexes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Filtered indexes are supported in SQL 2008 R2 Std.  I just created one.  I don't have a plain SQL 2008 instance handy, but they were introduced in 2008 so I'm inclined to think that they are there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Features differ between editions, not the actual SQL.

So `CREATE INDEX ... WHERE...` **must be** supported on all editions.

Indexed views are supported in all versions (`CREATE VIEW` and `CREATE INDEX ... ON MyView..`).  Its only how the optimiser uses them that differs which is unrelated to the DDL.

There is a heck of difference in the engine ignoring an indexed viw and ignoring a WHERE clause in an index: that's one hell of a breaking difference.

Comment: I thought partition tables used different SQL and that they only worked on high end editions

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: actually, good point. I meant the "WHERE" on the index. Which is slightly differenzt a entire CREATE PARTITION